# Python - Adding a key to an array, counting objects in child

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I've been trying to figure out how to add a group objects that are the same into a parent object and add a key to and add new parent array.

Here is the code for the first part - (adding the same objects in an array):

```
array = [{'userID': 32423, 'animal': 'Deer'}, {'userID': 92828, 'animal': 'Deer'},{'userID': 3382, 'animal': 'Bull'}]

res = {}
for item in array:
    res.setdefault(item['animal'], []).append(item)
```

However I can't figure out how to add a key and data called 'count' - which counts the number of objects in the parent object.

I can create an array like this:

```
[{'Deer': [
 {'userID': 32423, 'animal': 'Deer'}, 
 {'userID': 92828, 'animal': 'Deer'}
], 
'Bull': [
 {'userID': 3382, 'animal': 'Bull'}
]}]
```

How do I add a key to the object called 'count' which counts the objects in the child object?

How do I make it look like this:

```
[{'Deer': [
 {'userID': 32423, 'animal': 'Deer'}, 
 {'userID': 92828, 'animal': 'Deer'}
],
count: 2}, 
 {'Bull': [
 {'userID': 3382, 'animal': 'Bull'}
],
count: 1
}]
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why do you wish to have a `count` key? Why can't you just call `len()` on the array in the second code block?

Comment: If you simply want to count the number of animals for each type of animals in your initial array of objects you could just count it by iterating through `array` and simply making a dictionary with counts for each animal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a single iteration.

**Ex:**

```
array = [{'userID': 32423, 'animal': 'Deer'}, {'userID': 92828, 'animal': 'Deer'},{'userID': 3382, 'animal': 'Bull'}]

res = {}
for item in array:
    if item['animal'] not in res:
        res[item['animal']] ={item['animal']: [], 'count': 0}
    res[item['animal']][item['animal']].append(item)
    res[item['animal']]['count'] += 1
```

**Output:**

```
{'Bull': {'Bull': [{'animal': 'Bull', 'userID': 3382}], 'count': 1},
 'Deer': {'Deer': [{'animal': 'Deer', 'userID': 32423},
                   {'animal': 'Deer', 'userID': 92828}],
          'count': 2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

array = [{'userID': 32423, 'animal': 'Deer'}, {'userID': 92828, 'animal': 'Deer'},{'userID': 3382, 'animal': 'Bull'}]

grouped = {k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(array, key=lambda x: x['animal'])}
result = [{k: v, 'count': len(v)} for k, v in grouped.items()]

result
# [{'Deer': [{'userID': 32423, 'animal': 'Deer'}, {'userID': 92828, 'animal': 'Deer'}], 'count': 2}, {'Bull': [{'userID': 3382, 'animal': 'Bull'}], 'count': 1}]
```